# jquery ajax call does not stop repeating over and over again

Tags: jquery, ajax, call, repeat

Hello everyone I've never had a problem which i cant solve with google...
So this is the code:

```
function loadData(url, type){
        loading_show();  
        var quality = getCheckedRadio();
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://.../core.php",
            data: "url="+url +"&quality="+quality +"&type="+type,
            success: function (msg)
            {
                $("#url").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                {
                    //loading_hide();
                    //$("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");         
                    $("#url").html(msg);
                    window.onload=$("#url").fadeIn('slow');
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
}
function getmp3(id){
        var quality = getCheckedRadio();
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://.../core.php",
                data: "id="+id +"&quality="+quality,
                success: function (msgs)
                {
                    $("#dload").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                    {
                        loading_hide();
                        $("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");         
                        $("#dload").html(msgs);
                        window.onload=$("#dload").fadeIn('slow');
                    });
                }
            });
}
```

So, the first function works just fine, the core.php returns some html data and a javascript: " getmp3('bla'); " so it fires the second function. The problem is that the $.ajax in the 'getmp3' function repeats over and over again and it floods the browser. It does what it has to but it just doesnt stop calling over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the ajaxComplete functions, you can put the code directly in the success function.

```
function loadData(url, type){
        loading_show();  
        var quality = getCheckedRadio();
        $.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://.../core.php",
            data: "url="+url +"&quality="+quality +"&type="+type,
            success: function (msg)
            {
                    //loading_hide();
                    //$("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");         
                    $("#url").html(msg).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        });
        return false;
}
function getmp3(id){
        var quality = getCheckedRadio();
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://.../core.php",
                data: "id="+id +"&quality="+quality,
                success: function (msgs)
                {
                        loading_hide();
                        $("input[type=button]").removeAttr("disabled");         
                        $("#dload").html(msgs).fadeIn('slow');
                }
            });
}
```